# automatic differentiation used on 'real dataset' settles in false minima why?

Tags: tensorflow, automatic-differentiation

Hi so I've a done a project where we use tensorflow in automatic differentiation.  Using a fairly linear dataset  generated with numpy like so:

```
true_w, true_b = 7., 4.

def create_batch(batch_size=64):
    x = np.random.randn(batch_size, 1)
    y = np.random.randn(batch_size, 1) + true_w * x+true_b
    return x, y
```

when i try and repeat automatic differentiation with any other 'real' dataset from kaggle the weight and bias divert away from the intercept and coefficient from sklearn's or numpy's linear regression functions.  even using highly correlated features.  the following is using the Whisker-high Whisker-Low dataset from Kaggles World Happiness index 2022.  Tried other but these two have a very high correlation, I was assuming this would be the best attempt.

```
X = np.array(df['Whisker-high']).reshape(-1,1)
y = np.array(df['Whisker-low'])

reg = LinearRegression(fit_intercept=True).fit(X,y)

intercept = np.round(reg.intercept_,4)
coef = np.round(reg.coef_[0],4)

iters = 100
lr = .01

w_history = []
b_history = []

true_w = coef
true_b = intercept

w = tf.Variable( 0.65)
b = tf.Variable(1.5)

for i in range(0, iters):
    inds = np.random.choice(np.arange(0, len(df)), size=100, replace=True)
    X = np.array(df.iloc[list(inds)]['Whisker-high']).reshape(-1,1)
    y = np.array(df.iloc[list(inds)]['Whisker-low'])
    x_batch = tf.convert_to_tensor(X, dtype=tf.float32)
    y_batch = tf.convert_to_tensor(y, dtype=tf.float32)
    with tf.GradientTape(persistent=True) as tape:
        y = b + w *x_batch
        loss = tf.reduce_mean(tf.square( y - y_batch))
    dw = tape.gradient(loss, w)
    db = tape.gradient(loss, b)
    
    del tape
    
    w.assign_sub(lr*dw)
    b.assign_sub(lr*db)
    
    w_history.append(w.numpy())
    b_history.append(b.numpy())
    
    if i %10==0:
        print('iter{}, w={}, b={}'.format(i, w.numpy(), b.numpy()))

plt.plot(range(iters), w_history, label ='learned w')
plt.plot(range(iters), b_history, label ='learned b')
plt.plot(range(iters),[true_w] *iters, label='true w')
plt.plot(range(iters),[true_b] *iters, label='true b')
plt.legend()
plt.show()
```

although with automatic differentiation the weights and bias do seem to settle in a minima, a simple line plot over the data shows that it would be generous to says it's representative of the dataset.

```
plt.figure(figsize=(6,6))
plt.scatter(df['speeding'], df['alcohol'])
xseq = np.linspace(0, 9, num=df.shape[0])
plt.plot(xseq, b_history[-1] + w_history[-1]*xseq, color='green')
plt.xlabel('speeding', fontsize=16)
plt.ylabel('alcohol', fontsize=16)
plt.show()
```

Comment: and sorry the question would be how to get this to work or why would this be acting like so

Comment: and thinking it might be best to give context, i give data science give on [link](https://preply.com/en/?pref=NDU3ODY5OQ==)  I'm starting the to develop a deeplearning program and thought it would be fun to show this concept on a real dataset but well haven't been able to figure this out

Answer (score 0):

I figured out the answer. Itwas a datatype issue:

```
X = np.array(df.iloc[list(inds)]['Whisker-high']).reshape(-1,1)
```

Using numpy here is what caused the issue. I just needed to stick with tensors and not switch to an array here. Something to do with it not working with `GradientTape` as well.